# How to create AppInstanceAdmin using chime-sdk-identity cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I am trying to create an AppInstanceAdmin using the aws chime-sdk-identity CLI.

1. I created an application instance using the command: `aws chime-sdk-identity create-app-instance`.
2. I try to create an AppInstanceAdmin using the command:  `aws chime-sdk-identity create-app-instance-admin --app-instance-arn <arn> --app-instance-admin-arn ?`

And here's the problem. I can't create an admin instance because I need an admin account to do so.

My IAM user has the AdministratorAccess policy assigned.

I need AppInstanceAdmin to manage other accounts from my application. Now I am using a normal account, but I get an error `403 forbidden request when trying to create a channel for a messaging session`.

Comment: Did you create an `AppInstanceUser`  for yourself or do you have one?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I created it for myself using `aws chime-sdk-identity create-app-instace-user` CLI

Comment: Yes then it gives you an app instance user ARN. That’s what you use as the input to this command; basically you need to create a user and then ‘upgrade’ it.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary in the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/chime-sdk-identity/ CLI commands i can't see any command that can be used to `upgrade` the user.  Could you tell me which command I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CreateAppInstanceAdmin`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime-sdk/latest/APIReference/API_identity-chime_CreateAppInstanceAdmin.html) has a misleading name.

It doesn't *create* an admin, it *promotes* a user/bot to admin.

> CreateAppInstanceAdmin
>
> Promotes an `AppInstanceUser` or `AppInstanceBot` to an `AppInstanceAdmin`.

The description for the `AppInstanceAdminArn` could also be improved, as it incorrectly insinuates that you need to have the value from somewhere. I've provided feedback to the Chime team for its improvement.

> AppInstanceAdminArn
>
> The ARN of the administrator of the current AppInstance.

`--app-instance-admin-arn` is used to specify the ARN for the instance user / bot to be promoted.

```bash
➜  ~ aws chime-sdk-identity create-app-instance-user \
     --no-cli-pager \
     --name my-user-name 
     --app-instance-arn arn:aws:chime:xxx:yyy:app-instance/zzz \
     --app-instance-user-id my-user-id
{
    "AppInstanceUserArn": "arn:aws:chime:xxx:yyy:app-instance/zzz/user/my-user-id"
}
```

```bash
➜  ~ aws chime-sdk-identity create-app-instance-admin \
     --no-cli-pager \
     --app-instance-admin-arn arn:aws:chime:xxx:yyy:app-instance/zzz/user/my-user-id \
     --app-instance-arn arn:aws:chime:xxx:yyy:app-instance/zzz
{
    "AppInstanceAdmin": {
        "Arn": "arn:aws:chime:xxx:yyy:app-instance/zzz/user/my-user-id",
        "Name": "my-user-name"
    },
    "AppInstanceArn": "arn:aws:chime:xxx:yyy:app-instance/zzz"
}
```